# Combination of two dataframes - still show NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to fill my first dataframe with data from the second dataframe. Since I don't need and any special condition I suppose `combine_first` function looks like the right choice for me.

Unfortunately when I try to combine two dataframes result is still the original dataframe.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gen1': [5, None, 3, 2, 1],
                    'Gen2': [1, 2, None, 4, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Gen1': [None, 4, None, None, None],
                    'Gen2': [None, None, 3, None, None]})

df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Then, When I `print(df1)` I get df1 as I initiate it on the second row.
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: `combine_first` doesn't alter `df1`, it returns a new dataframe with the values filled in. You still need to assign that to something, like back to `df1` id you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me working nice if assign back output, but very similar method [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) working inplace:

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
   Gen1  Gen2
0   5.0   1.0
1   4.0   2.0
2   3.0   3.0
3   2.0   4.0
4   1.0   5.0
```

---

```
df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
   Gen1  Gen2
0   5.0   1.0
1   4.0   2.0
2   3.0   3.0
3   2.0   4.0
4   1.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`combine_first` returns a dataframe which has the change and not updating the existing dataframe so you should get the return dataframe

```
df1=df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Comment: It seems you miss already answered by same solution.